# Prestashop 1.6 - How I can get the admin directory name dynamically?

Tags: php, plugins, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to put my module in Prestashop market place, and make it standard everyone can use it. This plugin needs to know the admin directory name dynamically to do its service.

I have searched on the Internet a lot of times, but I didn't find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `_PS_ADMIN_DIR_` witch is set in `[your_admin_dir]/index.php`:

```php
if (!defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) {
    define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
}
```

This constant is only set when you're on an admin context. Your FrontOffice doesn't have knowledge of this directory and should not for obvious security reason.

There's also a `getAdminLink` method in class `Link`:

```php
/**
 * Use controller name to create a link
 *
 * @param string $controller
 * @param bool $with_token include or not the token in the url
 * @return string url
 */
public function getAdminLink($controller, $with_token = true)
{
    $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;

    $params = $with_token ? array('token' => Tools::getAdminTokenLite($controller)) : array();
    return Dispatcher::getInstance()->createUrl($controller, $id_lang, $params, false);
}
```

Example:

```php
// Here we create a link to the dashboard without token
$this->context->link->getAdminLink(Tab::getClassNameById(1), false)
```

Comment: Using _PS_ADMIN_DIR_ i get URI, a physic path to admin directory, what i want is url, to let employee access to admin interface by sending him an email.

Comment: I've added some more informations on method `getAdminLink()`

Comment: I get by getAdminLink method this link : index.php?controller=AdminDashboard. this last missed admin directory name.

Comment: there is, to my knowledge, no other way than using `PS_ADMIN_DIR` and concatenate it with `getAdminLink()` method.

Comment: I think i must create a formular to ask customer to insert his admin directory name in the back-office, and after getting the name, i would put it in the place of directory_name in this url : PS_BASE_URL_.__PS_BASE_URI__."directory_name".$link->getAdminLink('AdminEmployees', true);